# Eas Update does not publish any new Expo Updates

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-updates

I'm using EAS for configuring updates. The update isn't working. I tried the
`eas update` command and got the result as well:

```
✔ Linked to project @team/something
✔ Please enter an update message. … test
✔ Built bundle!
✔ Uploaded assets!
✔ Published!
```

Then, running `eas update:list` also, shows the list and all the group IDs. But on opening/closing the Android app, no updates are detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for my problem was the issue with the SDK version not set correctly.
It needed to be configured in `app.json` itself. In my case I solved it by adding:

```
"sdkVersion": "44.0.2",
```

to the `app.json` file.

Comment: Is this mentioned in the docs?

Comment: Does the change to app.json to add sdkVersion have to appear in an app store release, before published updates will respect it?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. Updates worked fine but after some update it stopped working.
Adding the runtimeVersion did the thing for us:

```
// app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "nativeVersion"
    }
  }
}
```